# how do I convert following python code to recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, sequence

I wish to generate a sequence of numbers such that I get:

```
(n - 10)^2, (n - 9)^2, ... n^2, ... (n + 9)^2, (n + 10)^2
```

I have the following code that does that via a loop:

```
def a_func(number):
start = -10
result = []
while start <= 10:
    result.append((number + start) ** 2)
    start += 1
return result
```

**How would I go about doing the same with recursion?**

Comment: Why? Why do you want recursion? Recursion is in almost every way worse than normal iteration

Comment: @12944qwerty While I agree in principle with this (particularly in python which has no tail call optimization), some problems can be solved more elegantly with recursion than with other strategies. at least in my opinion.

Comment: recursion was the requirement of the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part (in my mind) is determining how to "start" and "stop" based on your range between -10 and 10. Let's look at how we might do that with a closure.

Conceptually we are going to:

```
def func_a(n):
    ## ---------------
    ## Do "something" based on "n" and the current value of "i"
    ## ---------------
    def func_b(n,i):
        ## ---------------
        ## i is larger than our stopping point to stop
        ## ---------------
        if i > from_to[1]:
            return []
        ## ---------------

        ## ---------------
        ## i is within range so calculate "this" value
        ## and append all the additional values
        ## ---------------
        return [(n + i)**2] + func_b(n, i+1)
        ## ---------------
    ## ---------------

    ## ---------------
    ## This variable hidden inside the closure will allow
    ## us to specify where to start and stop our recursion
    ## ---------------
    from_to = (-10, 10)
    ## ---------------

    return func_b(n, from_to[0])

print(func_a(10))
```

Now let's clean it up a bit with a lambda:

```
def func_a(n):
    from_to = (-10, 10)
    func_b = lambda n, i: [(n + i)**2] + func_b(n, i+1) if i <= from_to[1] else []
    return func_b(n, from_to[0])

print(func_a(10))
```

This prints:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400]
```

Technically, `from_to` is not needed if you are happy hard coding those values. In that case you might do simply:

```
def func_a(n):
    func_b = lambda n, i: [(n + i)**2] + func_b(n, i+1) if i <= 10 else []
    return func_b(n, -10)

print(func_a(10))
```